# I wonder if it possible to use a gerund or an infinitive after “that”

Tags: clauses

Usually, in the book, I see “that” as a clause, but can the word “that” be before another clause?

> 1. *I don't think* [*that eating fruit every day is a problem*].
> 2. *I don't think* [*that it bores you to eat fruit every day*]
> 3. *I don't think* [*that eating fruit every day bores you*].

Comment: "That" is a subordinating conjunction, not a clause. In your examples, it introduces the underlined subordinate clauses.

Comment: If the word that is the subject of the verb in the clause, you can’t omit it. If it is the object of the verb, you can omit it. Here the word that is not the subject of the clause. But here it is: **I don't think /that is true**. You can't use: I don't think is true.